# Constraint for UPPERCASE on MySQL Column

Tags: mysql

I have a column called `UserID` with a type of `varchar(10)`. Is there a way to restrict that column to only accept UPPERCASE characters?

Comment: Add BEFORE INSERT and BEFORE UPDATE triggers and convert it to the correct case (or throw an error) in the triggers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked

> Is there a way to force [a MySQL] column to only accept UPPERCASE characters?

There is no constraint setting to do so.

@vatev suggested a pair of triggers to alter the data to make it uppercase. That could work. But it will have a performance cost.

If you use a case-insensitive collation, MySQL will treat your column as if it were single-case.  Most developers needing such limitations in their data use their UPDATE and INSERT statements to enforce those limitations.

```
INSERT INTO tab (col) VALUES (UPPER('data-item'))
```

will do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

The above answer by Ankit Saha is not quite right. This will set a CONSTRAINT that forces a field to be all upper case:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    uc_field VARCHAR(30),
    CONSTRAINT force_upper_case CHECK(BINARY uc_field = UPPER(uc_field))
);
```

If you want to force lower case, just change `UPPER()` to `LOWER()`

Tested on mariadb 10.2, but should work on any version of mysql/mariadb that supports `CHECK()` constraints.

Comment: Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

While creating your table set the constraint like this :

```
create table table_name(column_name check(column_name=upper(column_name)));
```

This will set a constraint that only uppercase data will be accepted.

Comment: This does not work due to @lfjeff's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing and updating the answer from @lfjeff:

The `BINARY expr` [is now deprecated on MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.3/en/cast-functions.html#operator_binary). As alternative, use:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    uc_field VARCHAR(30),
    CONSTRAINT force_upper_case CHECK(CAST(uc_field AS BINARY) = UPPER(uc_field))
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using the below mentioned query:-

UPDATE my_table SET my_column = UPPER(my_column)

All the best.